# Are there any websites that we can post our files online to use them in html files

Tags: file, posting

I do not have a website where we can upload stuff such as images and videos. Instead, I use HTML files for all my websites because they are just projects. The only thing is that I need to upload stuff so I can use the code anywhere.

First, I used Facebook and twitter to post my stuff, and it worked, but it was akward for my followers and/or friends. Then i used the urls for my files on my computers, but that doesn't work on other computers. Now, I'm searching for a website that we can post our files for coding.

Are there any websites that we can post our files for coding our there?

Comment: Off topic, but Github is pretty popular for hosting your code online, and Github Pages let you publish HTML pages too for free. It's also easier to sync files with git than by most other means.

Comment: What about using youtube for videos? Your image files should be in the same location as your HTML files. Are you familiar with relative vs absolute links? You should almost always use relative links when linking to your files. If you use relative links it should work on other computers just fine (though I'm not 100% sure by what you mean that it doesn't work).